# How do I give a client a certificate for our website?

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I apologise if this is a real noob question, but we have a server with IIS and it has a certificate, which has a private key, `mysite.domain.com`

I want to enable SSL and require client certificates in IIS for my website.

Am I right in thinking that I would export this certificate as a .CER and give it to someone who wants to access my website? And they just drop it into their certificate store (I assume it just goes into the right place)?

Or are there other steps? The certificate path shows there are two certificates higher up, TeleSec Business CA 1 and T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2. Do I need to do something with those as well?

I'm afraid I am a developer not a server admin. Many thanks.

Edit: I'm gonna elaborate, basically we have a server with IIS, if I enable SSL and Require client certificates, then they can't connect with a certificate/trust error. It made me think perhaps we need to give them a certificate. But I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: You should not need to export your certificate and provide it to them if your certificate is issued from trusted authority (seems like it is).

Comment: In that case, what does "Require client certificate" mean?

Comment: It means the client possesses certificate with a private key and presents it for authentication. The certificates for the clients are configured in IIS by you.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/

Comment: So I need to get a certificate from the client and map it to a website?

Comment: It looks like I might need to set up one to one mapping. I installed the role, but the guides I have say to right click the website, go to properties... but there is no properties option right clicking the website. I can't find it anywhere. This is server 2012 r2, IIS 6.2 according to help>about

Comment: I think I get it, although I'm not sure why it wants a username/password

Comment: I created a user, the guides said to disable all authentication methods in IIS for the site as part of the certificate process, so I am not sure if it'll work. I am not sure how to give the user permissions to view the website, or even if it's needed.

Comment: You are probably looking for mutual-cert auth.  See here: https://www.nevatech.com/blog/post/What-you-need-to-know-about-securing-APIs-with-mutual-certificates -- in which case you provide your server cert with a public key which the client trusts, and they provide their cert with a public key which your server trusts.  You then make sure your API requires mutual cert auth so that the certs must exist and be "trusted" (installed) on each side for it to authenticate and work.

Answer (score 1):

IIS require client certificate is a feature that never took off and has limited browser support. I would recommend you look into newer authentication features like:

1. FIDO U2F - Is just as secure as certificate authentication if not more secure because keys are stored on the u2f device.
2. TOTP/Google Authenticator - Secure and several code examples.
3. Yubikey Authentication - Very easy to code for and is very secure. Like U2f it does require a hardware token.

Comment: This is for a REST api rather than a browser, if that makes any difference

Comment: Where are you calling the REST API from? Is this a custom program that you wrote and if so, what language is it written in?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of using client certificate mapping? Why is this needed?

Comment: We have an API that is only allowed to be called by a single client. Although it is on a VPN already and firewalled, the idea is that only that single client can call it. It's written in .NET, and hosted on IIS. They gave us a certificate to use and we gave them ours. I reckon this one to one thing I've set up in IIS will do it.

Comment: Is the remote server certificate trusted on your machine? Can you try and visit the website in your web browser and see if you get a trust error?